What is the state of the art in Device-Independent QKD and Twin-Field QKD?
I understand that DIQKD would solve most problems related to QKD like side-channel attacks and with TFQKD we would also be able to avoid the use of quantum repeaters. So at least theoretically it seems that QKD's major setbacks have been solved. However when I read about QKD it seems to me that the general consensus is that it still has a lot of problems/challenges to overcome.
So is there a problem with DIQKD and TFWKD that makes them not practical? What is the current state of the art with QKD?

Measurement Device Independent (MDI) QKD is currently commercially available from at least one startup QKD vendor. Twin Field (which is a flavor of MDI) is being researched by at least one incumbent QKD vendor, but not yet commercially available. Fully Device Independent (DI) QKD is currently not commercially viable AFAIK.
